# Remove border and css from last column of the table

Tags: html, css

I want to remove `border` and `css` from last column of the `HTML` table and display as if that last column is not part of the `table` only and table has ended in second last column.

**Actual requirement : To display error image wherever there is error in the row.**

Please find my below code i have been trying:

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
#myTable tbody > tr:last-child > td {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>ffff</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
     <td><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42"></img></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abac</td>
    <td>dddd</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
     <td><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42"></img></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abcd</td>
    <td>fdfd</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
     <td><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42"></img></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abcde</td>
    <td>dddd</td>
    <td>UK</td>
     <td><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42"></img></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dert</td>
    <td>bbbb</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
     <td><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42"></img></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
     <td><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42"></img></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have created demo , Is this what you looking ?

```
  td:last-child {
  border :none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

***[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4t1be4o5/1/)***

Comment: You have colored the last row of the table to red?

Comment: I want to remove border and css from last column of the table

Comment: I have updated the Demo, Border is removed and color is made as white. Which looks as last element without Style

Answer (score 2):

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
}

th:not(:last-child),
td:not(:last-child) {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Steps: discard borders, set borders for all cells (except the last one in the row)

- Border-collapce property can discard table's borders, and then show td, th borders.
- Pseudoselectors :not(:last-child) will discard borders on the last cell for each row.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed two rules in your css:

```
td:not(:last-child), th:not(:last-child) { /* I just added ':not(:last-child)' here */
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td:not(:last-child) { /* And here */
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

I also suggest changing your images selectos in your html from `<img></img>` to `<img>` becuase "[The  tag is empty, it contains attributes only, and does not have a closing tag.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)".

[Here is my live example](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldd4pg33/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... to adjust the final column.

```
#myTable tbody > tr > td:last-child {
  border: 0;
  // any other options needed.
}
```

also, to remove other CSS, any css for the `td` should be styled ...

```
#myTable tbody > tr > td:not(:last-child) {
  // CSS for other columns
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is not in your code, check the `:last-child` attached to `td`, not the `tr`.  This will handle column, not row adjustment,